# How do i solve this strange error in my .Net MAUI page?

Tags: maui

Trying to learn MAUI i prepare a page where there is a Label that is hidden. At a certain event the label becomes visible. All it works ok, but when i put this label inside a "CollectionView" trying to bind her with a value from a database the Label become "not existing in the current context" with the error shown in this picture. Where is the error that i made? Thanks!
[image: Error]

The XAML Page with the CollectionView is this :
[image: XAML Pag]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!

Comment: This issue has been discussed numerous times.  You cannot reference items inside a template by name.  You need to use data binding to control templated UI elements from your VM

Comment: @Jason : Sorry for this. Can you link one of the discussion about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+x:name+template+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you cannot reference item inside a template by `x:Name`. You can use data binding to control templated UI elements from your ViewModel, just as Jason said.

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function.

You can refer to the following code:

1.try to add a new property `IsVisible` to your Item model, and bind it to your Label `Matr`. And you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your Item, if you change the value of item's property `IsVisible`, the UI will refresh automatically.

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    public int  Value { get; set; }

    public string Matricola { get; set; }

     // add property IsVisible
    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _isVisible, value); }
        get { return _isVisible; }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

2.create viewmodel (`TestViewModel.cs`)

```
public class TestViewModel:BaseViewModel 
{
    //add other code in this ViewModel

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }

    public TestViewModel() {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();   

        Items.Add(new Item { Id = 01, Value = 10, Matricola = "test1"});
        Items.Add(new Item { Id = 02, Value = 13, Matricola = "test2" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Id = 03, Value = 16, Matricola = "test3" });

    }
```

3.Usage example:

TestPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.TestPage"
             xmlns:MauiContentViewApp="clr-namespace:MauiContentViewApp;assembly=MauiContentViewApp"
             Title="TestPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Entry Grid.Column="0" 
                               BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                               Text="{Binding Value}" 
                               
                               Completed="Entry_Completed"  
                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Text="{Binding Matricola}"
                               
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                               FontAttributes="Italic" 
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

TestPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage 
{
      public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new TestViewModel();
      }

    private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {// here we can get the edited object and change the value of property `IsVisible` of this item ,then the `IsVisible` of `Matri` Label will be updated.
            Item item = (Item)((Entry)sender).BindingContext;

            if (item!=null && !item.IsVisible) {
            item.IsVisible= true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Zhang, many, many and many thanks for your answer!!! I've learned a lot of things with It!!!!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you. Have a nice day. :)